# Improvement of Game Tree in Forest: Visualisation of Backward Induction

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, forest, game-tree

I need help finishing my game tree in `forest` . I have successfully managed to represent the different levels and the basic structure of the tree with a continuum of moves, see the code.
However, I would now like to additionally represent the backward induction within the tree. The method I use for this are the diagonal strokes in the parent-child connections. Depending on whether the child is on the right or on the left, the diagonal line would look different, as shown in the picture (added by hand). Ideally, these strokes should be in red colour so that they are even easier to recognise.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest} 

\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,backgrounds, through, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\forestset{%
  auto edge label/.style={%
    before typesetting nodes={%
      if level=0{}{
        if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
          if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, right] {$##1$}
            },
          }{
            edge label/.wrap value={
              node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right] {$##1$}
            },
          },
        }{
          edge label/.wrap value={
            node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left] {$##1$}
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
        \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
        \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
      \end{scope}
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=2em,
    s sep=4em,
    auto edge label,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content
    }
  [A, my circle, arc below
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
    [B, my circle, edge label={}
        [{C}, my circle, edge label=0, arc below,
            [, coordinate , edge label={0}]
            [D, my circle, edge label={}
                [E, my circle, edge label={0}
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
                ]
                    [{0}, edge label={0}]
            ]
            [ , coordinate, edge label={0}]
       ]
    [{0}, edge label={0}]
    ]
    [, coordinate, edge label={0}]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I cant0 observe this ,,, diagram look very nice (well, shoed code was provided by package author)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested in the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\setistmathTF111
\setxtarrowtips<.4>{Bar}[thick]
\setistEllipseNodeStyle{2em}
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm}
\cntmdistance{20mm}{30mm}
\cntmAistb{0}[l]{0}[r]
\istrootocntmA(0){A}       \istbA       \endist
\istrooto(1)([yshift=-1em]0-1){B}
  \istb[->-]{0}[l]  \istb[->-]{0}[r]{0} \endist
\cntmAistb{0}[l]{0}[r]
\istrootocntmA(2)(1-1){C}  \istbA       \endist
\istrooto(3)([yshift=-1em]2-1){D}
  \istb[->-]{0}[l]     \istb{0}[r]{0}   \endist
\istrooto(4)(3-1){E}
  \istb[->-]{0}[l]{0}  \istb{0}[r]{0}   \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is easy enough to add the strokes by setting `edge label` to `node[midway]{/}` or similar. In the OP's situation, however, this won't work , because `auto edge label` usurps the `edge label` option (the option stores just the number, which is converted into the node specification before typesetting the nodes).

The solution is to redefine the edge numbering style to immediately add `node[<options>]{<number>}` to `edge label`. In the new code below, `auto edge label` should be called at individual nodes. It executes `edge label+={node[<options>]{#1}`, where `#1` is the given edge label; as before `<options>` are tailored to the position of the child.

Now we can similarly define `edge label stroke` to add a node containing an appropriate stroke symbol to `edge label`.

Note that both `auto edge label` and `edge label stroke` use `edge label+`, with the plus, to *add* to the edge label. This way, the two styles can be used in any order.

Incidentally, as both `auto edge label` and `edge label stroke` need to react to the position of the child (on the left of the parent, right below it, or on its right), I have generalized this logic into the `switch left middle right child` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest} 

\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,backgrounds, through, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}

%---------------------------------------------------------

\forestset{%
  % Execute keys #1/#2/#3 depending on whether this child is 
  % on the left of / just below  / or on the right of the parent.
  switch left middle right child/.style n args=3{
    if={n()>(n_children("!u")/2)}{
      if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{#2}{#3}
    }{#1}
  },
  % ADD the number to the edge label
  auto edge label/.style={%
    switch left middle right child=
      {edge label+={node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, left]{$#1$}}}
      {edge label+={node[midway, right ]{$#1$}}}
      {edge label+={node[midway, outer sep=1.5mm, right]{$#1$}}}
  },
  % ADD the stroke to the edge label
  edge label stroke/.style={
    switch left middle right child=
      {edge label+={node[midway,text=red,font=\bf]{\textbackslash}}}
      {edge label+={node[midway,text=red,font=\bf]{---}}}
      {edge label+={node[midway,text=red,font=\bf]{/}}}
  },
  nice empty nodes/.style={% page 65 of the manual - this is from the linguistics library
    for tree={
      calign=fixed edge angles
    },
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for parent={
          for children={anchor=north}
        }
      }{}
    }
  },
  arc below/.style={
    tikz+={%
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (.center) coordinate (o) -- (!1.north) coordinate (a) |- (!2.north) coordinate (b) -| (!3.north) coordinate (c) -- cycle;
        \node [draw, circle through={(b)}] at (o) {};
        \draw [\forestoption{edge}] () -- ($(o)!1!-35:(b)$) ($(o)!1!35:(b)$) -- ();
      \end{scope}
    },
    for children={
      if n=2{}{no edge},
    }
  }
}
\tikzset{%
  my circle/.style={draw, circle}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=2em,
    s sep=4em,
    nice empty nodes,
    math content
  }
  [A, my circle, arc below
    [, coordinate, auto edge label=0]
    [B, my circle, 
      [{C}, my circle, auto edge label=0, arc below, edge label stroke,
        [, coordinate , auto edge label=0]
        [D, my circle,
          [E, my circle, auto edge label=0, edge label stroke
            [0, auto edge label=0, edge label stroke]
            [0, auto edge label=0]
          ]
          [0, auto edge label=0, edge label stroke]
        ]
        [ , coordinate, auto edge label=0]
      ]
      [0, auto edge label=0, edge label stroke]
    ]
    [, coordinate, auto edge label=0]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```